# Fourier Transform Impulse

Tags: fourier, function

My friend and I are revising and we are confused on how to start the question below, and we're hoping someone could give us a hint. Sorry if it's a bit blurry.

We have the following equation, but aren't sure how to use it $$F(\omega)=∫f(t)e^{-j\omega t}dt $$

This is our task:

[image: FourierTransform]

Comment: Show what have you tried and at which point did you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Observe how *f(t)* is actually the sum of 2 rectangle functions. In terms of the step function *u(t)*, *f(t)* can be expressed as -

\begin{equation*}
f(t) = a_{1}\{u(t-\pi)-u(t+\pi)\} + (a_{2}-a_{1})\{u(t-\pi/2)-u(t+\pi/2)\}
\end{equation*}

Now I assume you know the standard formulas for the Fourier transform of a rectangular function.

Answer (score 0):

In the Fourier formula above, let f(t)=α for t=-π to π under that integral and again f(t)=α for t=-π/2 to π/2 in that integral.  The second integral merely adds α to the existing α making it 2α in the shorter interval.  By performing the integration correctly, you will get the answer given.  I did it.  P.S. the  f(t) shown is NOT an impulse.  An impulse exists from 0- to 0+ and is infinite in value.  The coefficient of an impulse represents it's area (mathematically) AKA it's strength in physical terms.  In the formula for F(ω) above, let t=0 since the impulse occurs only at t=0 and the integral reduces to the calculation of the area of the impulse which is 1 for a unit impulse. Hence 
F(ω)= 1 for a unit impulse.